# Is there a better way to play mp3 in java than Jlayer Lib?

Tags: java, audio, mp3

Im looking for a better library that can play me audio files (MP3 mostly), I'm using [Jlayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/sources.html) but its not up to date.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JLayer` code has not been changed in a long time, but neither has the API for the `javax.sound.sampled` library that it interacts with. While it's always had some deficiencies in design (imho), I don't know that it has broken.

If you wish to use `JLayer` with Maven, for example, there is a [github repository](https://github.com/pdudits/soundlibs) for that. Actually, it looks like JLayer is [now available through Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javazoom/jlayer/1.0.1).

You might want to take a look at bringing in *JavaFX* for audio playback. The class [MediaPlayer](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1.1/docs/api/javafx.scene.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.html) can play mp3s without requiring any additional libraries.

Comment: I was thinking of trying using JavaFX for audio playback, but had some difficulties, but i will give it another try, Thank you!

Comment: If you are using Java 8 it should go okay. Be sure and ask if you have any problems. The main drawback with JavaFX now is that if you aren't already using it in your program and you are using Java 9 or later, it complicates compilation and distribution.

Comment: I'm using Java 11 and i did work around the complications so far (I guess!), i did follow you advice and i managed to play MP3 on JavaFX successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I second [Phil's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62616933/942774) advice to look into JavaFX, if you are just interested in playback. That's currently probably the simplest route.

But if you want to dig a little deeper, i.e., access the audio data, and you're on Windows or macOS, you may want to try [FFSampledSP](https://www.tagtraum.com/ffsampledsp/index.html). It's an [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/)-based decoder supporting many other popular audio formats as well.

To use it via [Maven](https://maven.apache.org), just include this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tagtraum</groupId>
    <artifactId>ffsampledsp-complete</artifactId>
    <!-- (current version may differ) -->
    <version>0.9.32</version> 
</dependency>
```

Full disclosure: I'm the author of this library.